# Is it "Victory is mine" or "Victory is mines"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> Victory is mine.
>   Victory is mines.

I'm not sure if *mines* is even being used correctly here.

Comment: The Internet has a lot of information about possessive adjectives and pronouns: http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-possessive-adjectives.php

Comment: "Victory is mine." means "I am victorious".  "Victory is mines." appears to be a joke about naval battles. Please say where you found these sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is "mine"; there is no such possessive as "mines".

(My = Mine, Your = Yours, Her = Hers, Our = Ours, Their = Theirs)

Comment: No but "Victory is mines." is a valid and grammatical sentence.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK it is valid only in the bizarre circumstances of a joke ('mines' = stationary movement triggered explosives), so most people wouldn't understand you without that context.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, I mentioned the joke aspect in my comment under the question itself. When the asker doesn't provide sufficient context then I believe it's necessary for us to cover all possibilities. This is for the benefit of future users who have the same or a related question.